# Why is python's deque.reverse() so slow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, deque

Looking at the [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/dfc5e451b59e578b4e5eaddc34d4766271cb09dd/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L942) implementation of a deque, it appears that reverse() is written to be O(n) time. It seems to be just as slow in practice:

```
from collections import deque
import time
n = 100000
l = [i for i in range(n)]
d = deque(l)

start = time.time()
for _ in range(n):
    l.reverse()
print("list reversal", time.time() - start)
start = time.time()
for _ in range(n):
    d.reverse()
print("deque reversal", time.time() - start)
```

gives an output of:

```
list reversal 3.3866615295410156
deque reversal 4.0808796882629395
```

My question is, why isn't it O(1)? Couldn't you reverse a doubly linked list by setting a boolean to determine which side it considers the head? Is there a reason it needs to swap every item's location in memory?

Comment: Reversing is an uncommon operation. Adding a check of this flag to all the traversing methods may be considered unnecessary overhead to optimizing reversing. You can't just replace the head with the end, you have to switch from using the `next` link to the `prev` link.

Comment: Developers often not specify why they make one choice over another (nor put comments in the source code about this). The issue [#85581](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/85581) may help a bit though: "*Deques designed for fast access at the end points*". I guess opening an issue may help to know more about that but it looks like intentional.